# Python screen capture error

Tags: python, image, flask

I am trying to modify the code given [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask) for screen streaming. In the above tutorial it was for reading images from disk whereas I am trying to take screenshots. I receive this error.

> assert isinstance(data, bytes), 'applications must write bytes'
>   AssertionError: applications must write bytes

What changes should I make for it to work?

This is what I've done so far -

```
<br>index.html<br>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import time
# emulated camera
from camera import Camera

# Raspberry Pi camera module (requires picamera package)
# from camera_pi import Camera

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')


def gen(camera):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (frame)


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

camera.py

```
from time import time

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageGrab
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    grabber = Image.core.grabscreen

class Camera(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #self.frames = [open('shot0' + str(f) + '.png', 'rb').read() for f in range(1,61)]
        self.frames = [ImageGrab.grab() for f in range(1,61)]

    def get_frame(self):
        return self.frames[int(time()) % 3]
```

Full error : 
 [Link](http://pastebin.com/4691Npyk)

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: @xli added the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response payload must be a sequence of bytes. In the example, the images returned are JPEGs as `bytes` objects.

However, the image returned by `ImageGrab.grab()` is some PIL image class instead of bytes. So, try saving the image as JPEG as `bytes`:

```
import io
```

Take screenshot only for every iteration in gen:

```
class Camera(object):
    def get_frame(self):
        frame = ImageGrab.grab()
        img_bytes = io.BytesIO()
        frame.save(img_bytes, format='JPEG')
        return img_bytes.getvalue()
```

gen function:

```
def gen(camera):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
```

Comment: It still doesn't show any output but there are no errors.

Comment: You should use the yield statement from the original example that has the content-type: `yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')`

Comment: Only one frame or screenshot gets displayed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also I didn't see the edit before posting the last comment.